# update_post_meta does not work

Tags: wordpress

this is the code I have in a template file for testing.
when I open the page nothing happens in phpmyadmin
I do have a meta with this key cf_address
I do have a post with the id 436.

```
update_post_meta( 436, 'cf_address', 'kharia');
```

what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: is your meta_key already exists on this post ID?

Comment: yes its there. what if it doesnt exist?

Comment: If it doesnt, add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value) is called instead and its result is returned.

Comment: it doesn't work either. the meta key exists and nothing happens its really weird

Comment: @fogsy your code **should** work. Where are you putting the code exactly?

Comment: I put that one in a custom template file I am using. so requesttemplate.php. there is a page I created that uses the template

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your file is called. You can try 
`<?php die('My code is called here!');?>`